# output two tables from one input table in lua first output table will have all keys and second will have all values of input table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am having a table in lua

```
test = {fist=1,second=2,third=3}
```

I want to separate this table into two new table which will have values as :

```
keys = {first, second, third}
values = {1,2,3}
```

My try:

```
local keys = {}
local values = {}

for key , value in pairs(test) do
    table.insert(keys, key)
    table.insert(values, value)

end
```

Please let me know if any better option to do this.

Comment: Your solution does not work because the pairs in `t` are visited in unspecified order.

Comment: Also, you probably mean `keys = {"first", "second", "third"}`.

Comment: My reading of the original question was that you wanted the keys ordered by the values, but perhaps the title of the question implies something easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming arbitrary keys and values:

```
local keys, values = {}, {}

for k, v in pairs(input_table) do
    keys[#keys+1] = k
    values[#keys] = v
end
```

This is the fastest way with the above assumption.
Such table insertions are benchmarked and proven faster, at least in vanilla Lua.

Comment: @Prashant Gaur Do you need the pairs extracted in any specific order?

Comment: as they are passed into input table

Comment: That'll never work when the keys and values are **arbitrary** unless you catch every individual *addition* to your table.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the values in `t` are consecutive integers, this code should work:

```
out1={}
out3={}
for k,v in pairs(t) do
        out1[v]=k
        out3[v]=v
end
```

Note that the new tables are filled correctly even though the pairs in `t` are visited in unspecified order.

Answer (score 1):

My quick solution would be something like this:

```
local function split_table(input_table)
    local out_table1 = {}
    local out_table2 = {}

    for key, value in pairs(input_table) do --simply iterating input table
        table.insert(out_table1, key)
        table.insert(out_table2, value)
    end

    return out_table1, out_table2 --returning both output tables
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using a metatable and shadow tables to make a history tracking table that records the original order in which keys were added and modified.

Here's a lightly tested example, save as `track.lua`:

```
-- tracking table that keeps a history of keys in the
-- order they were added to the table.


-- safe markers to store to track the use of nil or NaN 
-- as either keys or values. Neither can be a key, and 
-- nil cannot be a value in a sequence. Note that the history
-- iterator will assume that the record of keys is a valid
-- sequence.
local nilmarker, nanmarker = newproxy(), newproxy()


-- Make a value that can server as either key or value in a
-- table, even if it is nil or NaN, neither of which can be
-- a table key or a value in a valid sequence.
local function safemark(v)
    if v == nil then return nilmarker end
    if v ~= v then return nanmarker end
    return v
end


-- Set a key and track it's history, potentially including
-- deletions since we use safe markers in the tracking tables.
local function t_newindex(t,k,v)
    local mt = getmetatable(t)
    if mt.__index ~= mt.shadow or not mt.shadow[k] then
        mt.k[#mt.k+1] = safemark(k)
        mt.v[#mt.v+1] = safemark(v)
    end
    mt.shadow[k] = v
    return mt and mt.shadow and mt.shadow[k]
end

-- Look up a key in the shadow table
local function t_index(t,k)
    return getmetatable(t).shadow[k]
end

-- simple module table
local tracked = {}

-- create a new table with tracked keys and values. If called
-- with no argument or false, only key creation and initial values
-- are tracked. If called with true, then every value change will
-- be tracked.
function tracked.new(fullhistory)
    local mt = {
        __newindex = t_newindex,
        shadow = {},
        k = {},
        v = {},
    }
    mt.__index = fullhistory and t_index or mt.shadow
    return setmetatable({},mt)
end


-- return a human-readable string describing a value,
-- paying attention to our private marks for nil and NaN
local function tracked.safe(v)
    if v == nilmarker then return "~~nil~~" end
    if v == nanmarker then return "~~nan~~" end
    return tostring(v)
end

-- return an iterator in history order of the keys and values
-- as they were created and updated. The history records nil
-- and NaN via private markers. To test for those markers, use
-- tracked.safe() to convert the possibly marked values to strings.
function tracked.history(t)
    local i = 0
    local mt = getmetatable(t)
    local k,v = mt.k, mt.v
    return function()
        i = i + 1
        return k[i], v[i]
    end
end

return tracked
```

Assuming it is available in the module path as "track.lua" then it can be used like this:

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\tmp\SOQuestions>lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> track = require "q19953449"
> t = track.new(true)
> t.a = 1
> t.b = 2
> t.a = 0
> t.c = 3
> for k,v in track.history(t) do print(k,v) end
a       1
b       2
a       0
c       3
> t.c = nil
> for k,v in track.history(t) do print(k,v) end
a       1
b       2
a       0
c       3
c       userdata: 007FD638
> t.d = 0/0
> for k,v in track.history(t) do print(k,v) end
a       1
b       2
a       0
c       3
c       userdata: 007FD638
d       userdata: 007FD658
> =t.d
-1.#IND
> =t.c
nil
> ^Z
```